# Avoid textbox Border onfocus?

Tags: css

The textbox `border-style` is initialized to `none`. But onfocus the border appears on the textBox. So, how to avoid the border appearance?

```css
input[type="text"]{
  
   border-style : none;
   box-shadow :  0 0 0 0;
   height : 3em;
   width : 20em;
 }

::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
  font-size : 16pt;
}

::-moz-placeholder { 
  font-size : 16pt;
}
```

```html
<label for='text'>Enter some text</label><br>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the way, `outline : none;` should be added to achive that:

```css
input[type="text"]{
  
   border-style : none;
   box-shadow :  0 0 0 0;
   height : 3em;
   width : 20em;
   outline : none;
 }

::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
  font-size : 16pt;
}

::-moz-placeholder { 
  font-size : 16pt;
}
```

```html
<label for='text'>Enter some text</label><br>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here">
```

Answer (score 1):

Set outline to none for this.

```
input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Sample snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        input {
            border: none;
        }
        
        input:focus {
            outline: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="font-family:sans-serif">
    <label for='text'>Enter some text</label>
    <br>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is another good option.